# TextView is not read by TalkBack if an OnLongClickListener is set

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback, android-a11y

I have a screen that is split up in several sections, each being a layout with `android:focusable="true"` set to true.
With TalkBack enabled, if you click one of these sections / layouts, Talkback will highlight that section and read every `TextView` inside of it.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/section1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 3" />

    </LinearLayout>

  ... other sections here 

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how the screen looks like when clicking the layout:

[image]

The layout is highlighted and TalkBack reads "Text 1, Text 2, Text 3".

Everything as expected.

But when I set a long click listener to one of the texts like:

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv2).setOnLongClickListener {
    Log.d("TAG", "clicked")
    true
}
```

that one particular `TextView` is not read anymore, but simply omitted. When I click the `TextView` directly (instead of the whole section / layout), it is still read.

How can I have the long click listener and the text still read by TalkBack when clicking the section?